# setState fora do constructor

Tags: react-native

Devs, criei um relogio que atualiza o state a cada segundo porém estou com a seguinte dúvida, alguém poderia me explicar o porque o setInterval só funciona corretamente se estiver dentro do constructor?

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date() }
    // setInterval( () => {this.setState({ date: new Date() })}, 1000)
  }
  setInterval( () => { this.setState({ date: new Date() }) }, 1000);

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 42, textAlign: 'center' }}> {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
}/* CLOCK END*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo a função setInterval() funciona no constructor devido a mesma ser renderizada quando criado o componente, assim sendo chamando a função. Da forma que passou o setInterval fora do render() a função não é renderizada assim nunca chamada por isso ela não executa.

Para executar corretamente o setInterval, aconselho que coloque a função dentro do componentWillMount conforme o código abaixo, ou utilize function components e use o Hook useEffect().

Código com componentWillMount.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <Text>Contador</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```